# Jacobian question -

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am stuck on a question in my calc III class which is shown above (part a). I completely understand how to find the Jacobian; however I don't understand why the relationship shown is true. How do I find the inverse transformation?

In terms of the Jacobian, I got $$J = \frac{1}{2u}$$.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Inverse Function Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: To find J(u, v) you wrote x and y in terms of u and v in preparation to do the differentiation.

For the inverse you first need to figure out how to express u and v in terms of x any y.

Comment: PS.  To prove that $\rm J_{(u,v)}=(J_{(x,y)})^{-1}$, we just show that $\rm J_{(u,v)}~J_{(x,y)}=I_2$ , via matrix multiplication and the chain rule for partial differentiation.